# Funcion groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

tengo un Dataframe en el cual necesito ubicar números de teléfonos repetidos (columna que estoy usando como ID de cliente) realmente lo que busco saber es cuantas veces ese cliente aparece en el DataFrame, pero no necesito solo eso, si no que también necesito que si el cliente esta 2 veces en el DataFrame se borre una de esas apariciones para que me quede solo una vez sus datos y me quede una columna "Numero de veces" con un 2, si es que el cliente aparece 2 veces.

Intente con una función GroupBy, pero no se como incorporar esta nueva columna obtenida a mi Dataframe original. Este es el código que estoy usando

```
Numero de veces=Comerciales.groupby(['Teléfono'])['Aproximaciones cliente'].count().reset_index()
```

Yo necesitaría que no me quede solo ese ultimo DataFrame, si no todo el DataFrame, con el numero de veces que aparece el numero de telefono y las filas con datos repetidos borradas.

Comment: Al principio dices que necesitas solo una fila por cliente, al final dices que necesitas el dataframe entero. no entiendo eso.
Si puedes proveer un ejemplo mejor.

Comment: Si quieres borrar repeticiones utiliza `drop_duplicates()` perosi lo que quieres es agrupar los datos, con `groupby()` es suficiente

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo de los datos que tienes?

Comment: ya lo solucione con drop_duplicates, muchas gracias Christian y Alfredo.